# Is this a bug in FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving

I am computing large numbers of zeros of RiemannSiegelZ.  It is easy to bracket a root with sign changes, so I am using Method->"Brent".  I observe the following:

```
In[1]:= Sign[RiemannSiegelZ[100000084757/10]]

Out[1]= -1

In[2]:= N[RiemannSiegelZ[100000084757/10]]

Out[2]= -0.263422

In[3]:= Sign[RiemannSiegelZ[40000033903/4]]

Out[3]= 1

In[4]:= N[RiemannSiegelZ[40000033903/4]]

Out[4]= 8.37005\[CenterDot]10^-6

In[5]:= FindRoot[
 RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, 100000084757/10, 40000033903/4}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> "Brent"]

During the evaluation of In[5]:= FindRoot::bbrac: Method -> Brent is only applicable to univariate real functions and requires two real starting values that bracket the root.

Out[5]= FindRoot[
 RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, 100000084757/10, 40000033903/4}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> "Brent"]
```

Is this a bug?  Obviously, I have "two real starting values that bracket the root".  Version 14.0.0.0

Comment: You second value is too close to 0.  Change it to 400000339031/40 and it works.  You can plot the function to see how sensitive it is to very slight changes in the second value.

Comment: @BillWatts    I get that, but why does FindRoot have to throw an error?  Wouldn't it be more user friendly to just return the second value, since it meets the AccuracyGoal?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a precision thing because if you work it this way, the root is outside your bracketed values.  Raise the WorkingPrecision and remove your accuracy goal and remove the Brent Method and get:

```
tsol = t /. FindRoot[RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, 100000084757/10, 40000033903/4}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*1.0000008475750013463132632678797550746035222765993*10^10*)
```

Check the solution

```
RiemannSiegelZ[tsol]
(*-8.*10^-36*)

tsol > 40000033903/4
(*True*)
```

So the actual root is larger than your second value.